# How to get location without GPS?

Tags: ios, gps

Say I want to know true heading. I only need very inaccurate estimation of location. How do I get that without GPS? What should I specify at CLLocation so it doesn't use GPS.

How do I ensure that the arrow sign doesn't show up on status bar if I do not use GPS anyway? Lest my customers will think that GPS is on.

Comment: Do you want to know heading (direction the device is pointing) or course (the direction the device is moving)? There is a big difference. The former can be done with a magnetometer, the latter requires GPS (or cellular/WiFi) position updates.

Comment: The latter requires very inaccurate location update. GPS is the most accurate. I mean by how much true heading changes as a function of location anyway?

Comment: OK, then you want course, not heading. Think of it this way - If you side step along a sidewalk to the north, but you are facing west, your course is to the north (that's the direction of your overall movement), but your heading is west (since that is the direction you are facing). It sounds like you want the course (the overall direction you are moving). You have no choice but to use CoreLocation.

Comment: No I want heading. The only reason why we need location is because north magnetic heading is slightly different than true north. But that doesn't differ a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That decision is up to the OS.  You can hint that you don't need accurate positions by setting the `desiredAccuracy` property to a non-accurate value.  The lowest cakCLLocationAccuracyThreeKilometers`.  Or you can use significant location change events instead (google it), but I'm not sure they work on devices without a cellular radio.  Pretty much the only way for an iPod touch or non-3G iPad to know its location is via GPS.  That's something you also need to think about.

Comment: You can get location data from WiFi too.

Comment: That's the reason for my choice of words ("pretty much").  Yes, you can get info from wifi, but how often are you connected to wifi on the go?